The fee structure of Youtube Data API
I am concerned about where the fees come from when I use YouTube Data API.
We tried to find out by looking at the official website and other websites, but it was not clear.
URL: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost?hl=ja
Therefore, we seek a clear explanation of the fee structure of YouTube Data API.
Best regards.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota you have 10,000 free quota per day.

Is there a charge for use beyond the 10,000 free quota per day?
If so, what system is used to incur them?

You cannot pay for additional quota but you can freely request some.

Based on the answers so far, am I correct in assuming that there is no money to be incurred when using the YouTube Data API?

You are right as far as I know.

The term cost based quote system is miss leading.
It doesn't cost money to use the API it costs quote points.
A new app is given 10000 quote points to test with.   You can use it as you wish each request you make costs a different amount of quote points to use.   Once you run out you will have to stop for the day.  The number will reset at midnight west coast USA time.
When you are done development you can request a quote extension and get more quote points.
This API is free to use
Intro to YouTube API and Cost-Based Quota: Everything You Need to Know
